# iOS 6 and 7 simulators in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How to have old simulators in new Xcode?

I have 2 SDKs (6.1 and 7.1) in my old Xcode 5.1.1 following path:

> Xcode.app -> right click and `<Show package contents>` ->
>   Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/

Copied both SDKs to my new Xcode, but Xcode only shows 8.4 and 9.0.

Is there any suggestion? Or maybe I can download it from somewhere (I believe there isn't)?

Comment: So you use XCode 7 or XCode 5.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode if you click Window->Devices, then on the bottom left click the '+' button, then Add Simulator.  There should be an option for selecting older versions of iOS Simulators.

If there isn't an option for iOS 6.1 or 7.1, after you click the '+' button, click the drop-down list for iOS Version and click download more simulators.  Then just pick which ones you want.

Comment: By this way, or the fastest way is by going to Preferences > Downloads > Components, there won't be old emulators. Only iOS 8.1 - 8.4 only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use simulator for iOS7 and earlier for XCode 7.1 - it's not compatible. Looks like Apple won't support them ever. It means you can't do this on simulator (you still can do this on real devices) at least in official way. You may not know that, but it also depends on your OSX:

- El Capitan supports iOS 8.1.
- Yosemite supports iOS 7.1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to use any iOS 7 simulators. However, an iPhone 4 running iOS7 connected to Xcode 7.3, on MacOS X 10.11.4 using the iOS 9 SDK runs just fine.

To support iOS 7 on all devices capable of running it, you will need LaunchImages for iPhone 4 and 5 (retina), and for iPad in portrait and landscape at 1x and 2x.

I would consider supporting iOS 6 at this point to be pointless. That's iPhone 3GS. iOS 7 is pushing it; I run my code on an iPhone 4 mostly to check that its fast enough.